# Storing in array or in fields? Which is better?

Tags: php, mysql

Today I was working on my website and I asked myself a simple question. 
Does storing an array with all informations is better than saving those one in different fields?
For example if I store a word, a password and a number in one field on the database in this way

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Value                                                          |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| all         | ["test","fa26be19de6bff93f70bc2308434e4a440bbad02","25468684888"] |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it better than saving it in this way?

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Value                                    |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| word        | test                                   |
| password    | fa26be19de6bff93f70bc2308434e4a440bbad02 |
| number      | 25468684888                              |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I think that the first method is faster than the last one because you need only to SELECT one field and not three or more. What do you think about it?

Comment: None. The one you call field, is actually a column. You need, for instance, for an user, a column for `id`, `username`, `password`, etc

Comment: While most will immediately say *the second one*, it may depend. Voting to close as too broad and opinionated.

Comment: It rarely depends in this case.

Comment: There is something called db normalization.

Comment: There are limited cases where putting several values in a column makes sense - small numbers of serialised attributes against users (or other things) works quite well (Wordpress does this for some config items, I believe). However in general you should not do this - as soon as you need to join, it will become a mess unless you have it properly normalised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second method. By far.

You should never put more than one piece of data into a single column.

A single row of data shuld contain all the information you need:

```
id  name    password
1   Fluff   itsASecret
2   Flupp   Ohnoes
```

Basically, it has to do with updates, selects, searches and pretty much everything that databases do. They are made to do it on single columns, not little bits of data inside a string.

Taking your example, how do you update the password? How do you put an index on the user ID?

What if you also had a bit of data called "NumberOfVotes" If you had it all in one column in a pseudo-array, how do you get a tally of all the votes cast by all users? Would you REALLY want to pull each entry out into PHP, explode it out, add it to the running total and THEN display how many votes have been cast? What if you had a million users?

If you store everything in a ingle column, you could do a tally really easily like this:

```
select
    sum(NumberOfVotes)
from
    yourTableName
```

Edit (Reply to faster query):

Absolutely not, the time it takes to compelte a query will come down to two things:
1) Time it takes to execute the query
2) Time it takes to return all the data.

In this case, the time it takes to return the data will be the same, after all, the database is returning the same amount of bytes. However, with tables that are properly set up, just FINDING the right data will be faster by orders of magnitue.

As an example of how difficult it would be to simply USE a table that has the various bits of information all mumbled together, try to write a query to update the "number" value in the row that starts with the word "test".

Having said that, there are possibly some potential cases where it can in fact be okay to store multiple "fields" of data in one column. I once saw (and copied) an exceptionally interesting permissions system for users that stored the various permissions in binary and each digit in the number equated to being allowed/not being allowed to perform a certain type of action. That was however one interesting example - and is pretty much what I would call an exception that proves the rule :)

Comment: If field set is constant, I think none of that methods is correct - since the best way is to create 3 columns and store values in them

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo His second option WAS to have three columns?

Comment: Glad I can make it +1

Comment: @Fluffeh - no, his second option was to have 2 columns and store field values via name of field and value of field (i.e. 3 rows for 3 fields)

Comment: @Fluffeh - I putted the ID just to do an example, let me tell another example.
If I have all notifications users stored in one array, will it be better than getting them once by once? and if I need all array's data once? Will the second method be faster than the first one?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Hmm, that's not the way that I read it. It looked like three columns to me. I will make an edit so that he definately gets it, but I think he was asking about three columns.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks mate, you know what they say, even a stopped clock is right twice a day.

Answer (score 2):

> I think that the first method is faster

is your **main** problem actually. You are comparing solutions from only "is it faster" point of view. While you have no measure to tell if there is any difference at all. Or, if even there is, if such a difference does matter at all. So, the only your reason is a **false one.** While you completely overlook indeed important, essential reasons like **proper database design.**

Comment: I think that it's really the main problem. You can have a nice "database design" but if it isn't fast and efficent it is only a waste of time.

Comment: It is called "proper" for a reason.

Comment: Yup, I wanted **only** to know which was better and why.

Answer (score 1):

Saving in separate fields is a lot more flexible as you are then able to easily search/manipulate data using SQL queries, whereas if they were in an array you would frequently find yourself needing to parse data outside SQL. Consider the following example:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Value                                                          |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| all         | ["1","fa26be19de6bff93f70bc2308434e4a440bbad02","25468684888"] |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using the above table, you need to find the number field for the user with id 1, however there is nothing to search for, you can't simply to a query for the value 1 somewhere in the `all` field, as that would find every instance of the number 1!

You'll also encounter this problem when changing data in your DB, as you'll have to get the current array, parse it, change the value, then reinsert it.

Also you'll need to put some form of ID as a field to act as a primary key.

However with separate fields for each value, it's fairly simple:

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Value                                    |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| id          | 1                                        |
| password    | fa26be19de6bff93f70bc2308434e4a440bbad02 |
| number      | 25468684888                              |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+

SELECT `number` FROM mytable WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The second option is better because its more readable and maintainable.

If someone who didnt write the code has to maintain it, the first option is terrible.
If you ever need to change a field, or add a field, likewise, the first option is a nightmare.

The second option requires much less work.

Keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

I think given example is trivial and that's why answer for specific example is 2nd method. But there are time's when first method is far more easy to implement. For example you create pages for website dynamically from admin panel, and in start you don't know all the values that will be used in every page. So you put general options like in 2nd method, and put something like page_data and use it to store serialized object. Now you should use serialized object for data that are not likely to change individually, as they are treated as single piece of data.

In your code you fetch serialized object, do unserialize and use them as normal. This way you can add page specific data that are not generalized for every page, but still the page's are the same.

Comment: "far more easy to implement" is a straight road to nightmare. Too many a developers bitten the dust thinking this way. Please don't let the laziness be your guide.

Comment: @YourCommonSense So if user want to create 1000+ page's where every page need one different column, you're saying go, create 1000 tables. I'm not saying it's first method to look at, just don't say it's bad in every possible case. Also I wrote that those data are looked as single piece and should be treated as such.